# how do you distinguish two tables in an @foreach in the view?

Tags: laravel

The code may seem a little complicated, but, soon, I have two tables, one for users and one for orders, and I have both related with "join" and when I go to my display and do $order->created_at calls the user table and the value you want to call is in the order table, is there any way to do this without changing the name of the columns?
Thanks to anyone who can help

```
<td>{{$encomenda->updated_at}}</td>

$minhasencomendas= encomendas::where('id_user', $this->user->id)
            ->join('encomendas_estados', 'encomendas.estado', '=', 'encomendas_estados.id')
                ->join('users', 'encomendas.id_user' , '=', 'users.id')
                ->join('encomendas_detalhes', 'encomendas.id' , '=', 'encomendas_detalhes.id_encomenda')
                ->orderBy('encomendas.id', 'asc')->get();
```

Comment: I answered your question, but in this method you need to select your all field, that you want to select. Only selected data will send to collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your both table field name are same, then  you can change your field name with `select` method, like :

```
->select('users.id as user_id','encomendas_estados.created_at as encomendas_estados_created_at');
```

Then you can access by :

```
<td>{{ $encomenda->encomendas_estados_created_at }}</td>
```

Comment: thanks men worrkkss i dont remember more of select ahah thankyou

Comment: Glad to know that it helped :)